# The statistic of the number of "UDU's impressions" in Dyck paths.

Tags: combinatorics

How can I find the statistic of the number of "UDU's impressions" in DYCK paths?
What is the number of DYCK paths when there is no UDU string?
I have find some information about this but it was not obvious or clear to me.
I would appreciate help and navigation.

Comment: What did you find that was not clear?

Comment: @BMath what i found.. appear below in the answer of another user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at the paper *[Statistics on Dyck Path](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Mansour/mansour86.pdf)* by Toufik Mansour. See also the references given there, especially [9] Y. Sun, *[The statistic number of udu's in Dyck paths](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04003036)*, Discr. Math. 287 (2004), 177–186.

In particular, by Theorem 2.2 in [9] for $x=0$, we find that for no "UDU"  the generating function is
$$T(0,z) =\frac{ 1 + z - \sqrt{1-2z-3z^2} }{2z}
=1+x+x^2+2x^3+4x^4+9x^5+21x^6+51x^7+\dots.$$
See the related sequence is [A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006).

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04003036&ved=2ahUKEwjyj5mxmsnmAhX6A2MBHWDMD2oQFjAAegQIBxAE&usg=AOvVaw0RrYaeRf-il7JSHpPCWGWn&cshid=1577016089763 i also looked at what u sent

Comment: @Maths1999_ Well done!

Comment: i would ask how did you find the generating function when there is no UDU's ? I have did x=0 in T(x,z) in the second article above but did not get the same function as u! @Robert Z

Comment: @Maths1999_ Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! Now that is what i got for no UDU's impressions. Is there a combinatorial explanation for this phenomenon? @Robert Z

Comment: @Maths1999_ You should read the proof of Theorem 2.2 in [9] based on the symbolic method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102490/discussion-between-maths1999-and-robert-z).